# Получение данных в TreeView из WCF сервиса

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Доброго времени суток! 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Есть код, который получает данные из WCF сервиса:

```
BasicHttpBinding bd = new BasicHttpBinding();
        CashService.RemoteCashContractClient client = new CashService.RemoteCashContractClient(bd, new EndpointAddress("http://......."));
        CashService.CatalogRecord[] myStocks = client.GetStockList();
```

Но вот не могу понять как вывести эти данные в `TreeView`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как корректно это сделать?
Заранее, благодарю.

Comment: WinForms или Wpf? TreeView родной или DevExpress например? Если код получения данных не вызывает проблем, добавлять его в вопрос нет смысла, лучше добавьте код того, как вы пытались добавлять данные в TreeView, и что не получилось

Comment: @rdorn, реализовать мне нужно в простом Windows Form, не в DevExpress, и желательно на .NET 4.0. Примера создания моего TreeView толком нет, так как не знаю как это правильней реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный TreeView в WinForms не поддерживает привязку данных, поэтому его необходимо заполнить в ручную

```
private void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Коллекция элементов которые будем добавлять в TreeView
    //тут может быть вызов сервиса например
    List<CatalogRecord> catalogRecords = new List<CatalogRecord>()
    {
        new CatalogRecord
        {
            Name = "Яблоко"
        },
        new CatalogRecord
        {
            Name = "Груша"
        },
        new CatalogRecord
        {
            Name = "Помидор"
        }
    };


    //Так как стандартный TreeView не поддерживает привязку данных
    //то проходим по сформированной ранее коллекции и заполянем TreeView в ручную
    foreach(var record in catalogRecords)
    {
        tvTest.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode {Text = record.Name });
    }

}
```

Comment: Для имитации привязки, можно хранить ссылку на "привязанный" элемент в свойстве `Tag` ноды, не то чтобы очень удобно, но так хотя бы можно знать кого кликнули например.